# Simulate click on next image

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I am making some simple slider with jQuery with left, right buttons (on the button click i want to simulate click on the next image with class gthumb and set class active to it)

HTML:

```
<div class="gleft"></div>
<div class="gright"></div>
    <div class="gal-thumbs">
    <a href="#" class="gthumb active"><img src="/sites/zum.kz/themes/lounge/gal/pub/pub1.jpg"></a>
    <a href="#" class="gthumb"><img src="/sites/555.kz/themes/lounge/gal/pub/pub2.jpg"></a>
    <a href="#" class="gthumb"><img src="/sites/555.kz/themes/lounge/gal/pub/pub3.jpg"></a>
    <a href="#" class="gthumb"><img src="/sites/555.kz/themes/lounge/gal/pub/pub4.jpg"></a>
    <a href="#" class="gthumb"><img src="/sites/555.kz/themes/lounge/gal/pub/pub5.jpg"></a>
    </div>
```

JS:

```
    // change background on arrow click
    var current_img = $('.gthumb.active');

    $('.gleft').live('click', function() {
        current_img.next().trigger('click').addClass('active');
    });
```

When you click on `.gleft` it should simulate click on next image from an image with `.active` class. However, when i click on `.gleft` nothing happens. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its probably not the best way to create a slider but in terms of fixing what you have already this should be sufficient to get you started.

```
$('body').on('click','.gleft', function() {
    if($('.gthumb.active').next().length > 0){
        $('.gthumb.active').removeClass('active').next().trigger('click').addClass('active');
    }
});
$('body').on('click','.gright', function() {
    if($('.gthumb.active').prev().length > 0){
        $('.gthumb.active').removeClass('active').prev().trigger('click').addClass('active');
    }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/T9uY8/

Comment: Thanks! Can you explain why we have used length here?

Comment: @Heihachi `.length` is being used here to check to see if the `.next()` element exists. Length is kind of like a count of an element.

Comment: And why when we are using on(), you selected body element then on()?

Comment: @Heihachi It's called [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) and allows you to listen for events on future instances of elements that may be added at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

This should cover all your bases...

```
// Click to go right
$('body').on('click', '.gright', function() {
    if($('a.active').next().length != 0){
    $('a.active').removeClass('active').next().addClass('active').trigger('click');
    }
});

// Click to go left
$('body').on('click', '.gleft', function() {
    if($('a.active').prev().length != 0){
    $('a.active').removeClass('active').prev().addClass('active').trigger('click');
    }
});

// Just to show the click is being triggered
$('body').on('click', '.gthumb', function(){
    alert('I have been clicked!!');
});
```

[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/r5CSZ/4/)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `live` has been deprecated, you should just use `on`, see here http://api.jquery.com/live/

To trigger a click, you only need to call `click()`

```
var current_img = $('.gthumb.active');

$('.gleft').on('click', function() {
    current_img.next().click().addClass('active');
});
```